# Using perf_event with the ARM PMU inside gem5

Tags: linux, arm, gem5

I know that the ARM PMU is partially implemented, thanks to the gem5 source code and some publications.

I have a binary which uses perf_event to access the PMU on a Linux-based OS, under an ARM processor. Could it use perf_event inside a gem5 full-system simulation with a Linux kernel, under the ARM ISA?

So far, I haven't found the right way to do it. If someone knows, I will be very grateful!

Comment: Hi Pierre, are you hitting gem5 specific problems or is it a more general question on how to use them? If possible, try to first deal with the more general question on a more stable/fast simulator like QEMU/real hardware, and only then come to gem5 (which slower and generally buggier). Not sure QEMU supports it though, but worth checking.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Maybe I should have been more precise. Currently, I have a binary (developed by myself) which uses perf_event on real ARM hardware, to get cache misses and mispredicted branches, and it works well. My perf_event_attr.type is configured with PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE and the .config field with PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES and another with PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES. However, when i put this binary on a gem5 fs simulation, configured with the DerivO3CPU, ArmSystem, and RealView platform, I got the following error "ENOENT (2): No such file or directory"

Comment: I don't know if we can access the PMU through perf_event into gem5. If so, maybe we have to use RAW events? In the gem5 example code under configs, I have found a snippet in devices.py which "Instantiates 1 ArmPMU per PE" (addPMUs()). However, after few tries, I don't understand how to use this and how it is related to perf_event.

Comment: OK, thanks for clarifying. So the based on  ENOENT, the `perf_event` file is not being created by the Linux kernel is that it? I'll ask around.

Comment: The `perf_event` file... descriptor, you mean? Yes, it is **not** created by the kernel (equal to `-1`).  I wish to precise that this error arrives at the return of the `perf_event_open()` _syscall_. Finally, this error is documented in the `perf_event_open.2` _manpage_, and also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47829826/perf-event-open-can-not-open-more-than-7-fd)

Comment: Just a temporary reply hopefully until I get better replies, could you try to just patch the scripts to call `addPMUs`/do exactly what it does on CPUs? And pass a PPI interrupt (<31 and free according to the RealView.py file interrupt map). The `events` argument is optional, and all architectural events should be available once `addArchEvents` gets called.

Comment: @Ciro I used a code similar to `addPMUs()` in `devices.py`, with interrupts number 20, 21, 22, and 23 (one by core) according to the _RealView_ interrupts mapping, with the `ArmPPI` class. However, `perf_event_open()` still return the same error. Note that I got this message during the boot, from `src/arch/arm/pmu.cc:293`: `warn: Not doing anything for write to miscreg pmuserenr_el0`. This register is documented in the _ARMv8-A architecture manual_. Do you know if `perf_event` is supposed to be initialized with `PERF_EVENT_HARDWARE` or `PERF_EVENT_RAW`, to be used with _gem5_?

Comment: @Ciro With `--debug-flags=PMUVerbose`, I get the following:
`0: system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.isa.pmu: Initializing the PMU.`
[...]
`0: system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.isa.pmu: PMU: Adding Probe Driven event with id '0x2'as probe system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.itb:Refills`
[...]
`8687351673751: system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.isa.pmu: Assigning PMU to ContextID 0.`
[...]
`8687351673751: system.cpu_cluster.cpus0.isa.pmu: updateCounter(31): Disabling counter`
[...]

Comment: OK. I'm afraid I don't know much about the PMU events and how they are exposed to Linux :-( I'll let you know if anyone replies to me, and if you manage to progress, do make an answer. It would also be amazing if you could share a minimal C program for reproduction, even though it is supposedly not hard to find one online.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway, I appreciate. I will try to ask on the _gem5_ mailing list. If I find something that works, I will post it here for sure. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Context

I was not able to use the *Performance Monitoring Unit* (*PMU*) because of a *gem5's* unimplemented feature. The reference on the mailing list can be found [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg18401.html). After a personal patch, the *PMU* is accessible through `perf_event`. Fortunately, a similar patch will be released in the official *gem5* release soon, could be seen [here](https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-dev@gem5.org/msg36218.html). The patch will be described in another answer, due to the number of link limitation inside one message.

## How to use the *PMU*

### *C* source code

This is a minimal working example of a *C* source code using `perf_event`, used to count the number of mispredicted branches by the branch predictor unit during a specific task:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/perf_event.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    /* File descriptor used to read mispredicted branches counter. */
    static int perf_fd_branch_miss;
    
    /* Initialize our perf_event_attr, representing one counter to be read. */
    static struct perf_event_attr attr_branch_miss;
    attr_branch_miss.size = sizeof(attr_branch_miss);
    attr_branch_miss.exclude_kernel = 1;
    attr_branch_miss.exclude_hv = 1;
    attr_branch_miss.exclude_callchain_kernel = 1;
    /* On a real system, you can do like this: */
    attr_branch_miss.type = PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE;
    attr_branch_miss.config = PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES;
    /* On a gem5 system, you have to do like this: */
    attr_branch_miss.type = PERF_TYPE_RAW;
    attr_branch_miss.config = 0x10;
    
    /* Open the file descriptor corresponding to this counter. The counter
       should start at this moment. */
    if ((perf_fd_branch_miss = syscall(__NR_perf_event_open, &attr_branch_miss, 0, -1, -1, 0)) == -1)
        fprintf(stderr, "perf_event_open fail %d %d: %s\n", perf_fd_branch_miss, errno, strerror(errno));
    
    /* Workload here, that means our specific task to profile. */

    /* Get and close the performance counters. */
    uint64_t counter_branch_miss = 0;
    read(perf_fd_branch_miss, &counter_branch_miss, sizeof(counter_branch_miss));
    close(perf_fd_branch_miss);

    /* Display the result. */
    printf("Number of mispredicted branches: %d\n", counter_branch_miss);
}
```

I will not enter into the details of how using `perf_event`, good resources are available [here](http://web.eece.maine.edu/%7Evweaver/projects/perf_events/), [here](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/perf/design.txt), [here](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man2/perf_event_open.2.html), [here](http://rts.lab.asu.edu/web_438/project_final/CSE_598_Performance_Monitoring_Unit.pdf). However, just a few notes about the code above:

- On real hardware, when using `perf_event` and *common events* (events that are available under a lot of architectures), it is recommended to use `perf_event` macros `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` as type and to use macros like `PERF_COUNT_HW_BRANCH_MISSES` for the number of mispredicted branches, `PERF_COUNT_HW_CACHE_MISSES` for the number of cache misses, and so on (see the manual page for a list). This is a best practice to have a portable code.
- On a *gem5* simulated system, currently (v20.0), a *C* source code have to use `PERF_TYPE_RAW` type and architectural event ID to identify an event. Here, 0x10 is the ID of the `0x0010, BR_MIS_PRED, Mispredicted or not predicted branch` event, described in the *ARMv8-A Reference Manual* ([here](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0487/latest/)). In the manual, all events available in real hardware are described. However, they are not all implemented into *gem5*. To see the list of implemented event inside *gem5*, refer to the `src/arch/arm/ArmPMU.py` file. In the latter, the line `self.addEvent(ProbeEvent(self,0x10, bpred, "Misses"))` corresponds to the declaration of the counter described in the manual. This is not a normal behavior, hence *gem5* should be patched to allow using `PERF_TYPE_HARDWARE` one day.

### *gem5* simulation script

This is not a entire *MWE* script (it would be too long!), only the needed portion to add inside a full-system script to use the *PMU*. We use an *ArmSystem* as a system, with the *RealView* platform.

For each *ISA* (we use an *ARM* *ISA* here) of each *CPU* (*e.g.*, a `DerivO3CPU`) in our cluster (which is a `SubSystem` class), we add to it a *PMU* with a unique interrupt number and the already implemented architectural event. An example of this function could be found in `configs/example/arm/devices.py`.

To choose an interrupt number, pick a free *PPI* interrupt in the platform interrupt mapping. Here, we choose *PPI* n°20, according to the `RealView` interrupt map (`src/dev/arm/RealView.py`). Since *PPIs* interrupts are local per *Processing Element* (*PE*, corresponds to cores in our context), the interrupt number can be the same for all *PE* without any conflict. To know more about *PPI* interrupts, see the *GIC* guide from *ARM* [here](https://developer.arm.com/architectures/learn-the-architecture/arm-corelink-generic-interrupt-controller-v3-and-v4-overview/single-page).

Here, we can see that the interrupt n°20 is not used by the system (from `RealView.py`):

```
Interrupts:
      0- 15: Software generated interrupts (SGIs)
     16- 31: On-chip private peripherals (PPIs)
        25   : vgic
        26   : generic_timer (hyp)
        27   : generic_timer (virt)
        28   : Reserved (Legacy FIQ)
```

We pass to `addArchEvents` our system components (`dtb`, `itb`, etc.) to link the *PMU* with them, thus the *PMU* will use the internal counters (called *probes*) of these components as exposed counters to the system.

```
for cpu in system.cpu_cluster.cpus:
    for isa in cpu.isa:
        isa.pmu = ArmPMU(interrupt=ArmPPI(num=20))
        # Add the implemented architectural events of gem5. We can
        # discover which events is implemented by looking at the file
        # "ArmPMU.py".
        isa.pmu.addArchEvents(
            cpu=cpu, dtb=cpu.dtb, itb=cpu.itb,
            icache=getattr(cpu, "icache", None),
            dcache=getattr(cpu, "dcache", None),
            l2cache=getattr(system.cpu_cluster, "l2", None))
```

Answer (score 2):

As of September 2020, *gem5* needs to be patched in order to use the *ARM PMU*.

**Edit**: As of November 2020, *gem5* is now patched and it will be included in the next release. Thanks to the developers!

## How to patch *gem5*

This is not a clean patch (very straightforward), and it is more intended to understand how it works. Nonetheless, this is the patch to apply with `git apply` from the *gem5* source repository:

```
diff --git i/src/arch/arm/ArmISA.py w/src/arch/arm/ArmISA.py
index 2641ec3fb..3d85c1b75 100644
--- i/src/arch/arm/ArmISA.py
+++ w/src/arch/arm/ArmISA.py
@@ -36,6 +36,7 @@
from m5.params import *
from m5.proxy import *

+from m5.SimObject import SimObject
from m5.objects.ArmPMU import ArmPMU
from m5.objects.ArmSystem import SveVectorLength
from m5.objects.BaseISA import BaseISA
@@ -49,6 +50,8 @@ class ArmISA(BaseISA):
cxx_class = 'ArmISA::ISA'
cxx_header = "arch/arm/isa.hh"

+    generateDeviceTree = SimObject.recurseDeviceTree
+
system = Param.System(Parent.any, "System this ISA object belongs to")

pmu = Param.ArmPMU(NULL, "Performance Monitoring Unit")
diff --git i/src/arch/arm/ArmPMU.py w/src/arch/arm/ArmPMU.py
index 047e908b3..58553fbf9 100644
--- i/src/arch/arm/ArmPMU.py
+++ w/src/arch/arm/ArmPMU.py
@@ -40,6 +40,7 @@ from m5.params import *
from m5.params import isNullPointer
from m5.proxy import *
from m5.objects.Gic import ArmInterruptPin
+from m5.util.fdthelper import *

class ProbeEvent(object):
def __init__(self, pmu, _eventId, obj, *listOfNames):
@@ -76,6 +77,17 @@ class ArmPMU(SimObject):

_events = None

+    def generateDeviceTree(self, state):
+        node = FdtNode("pmu")
+        node.appendCompatible("arm,armv8-pmuv3")
+        # gem5 uses GIC controller interrupt notation, where PPI interrupts
+        # start to 16. However, the Linux kernel start from 0, and used a tag
+        # (set to 1) to indicate the PPI interrupt type.
+        node.append(FdtPropertyWords("interrupts", [
+            1, int(self.interrupt.num) - 16, 0xf04
+        ]))
+        yield node
+
def addEvent(self, newObject):
if not (isinstance(newObject, ProbeEvent)
or isinstance(newObject, SoftwareIncrement)):
diff --git i/src/cpu/BaseCPU.py w/src/cpu/BaseCPU.py
index ab70d1d7f..66a49a038 100644
--- i/src/cpu/BaseCPU.py
+++ w/src/cpu/BaseCPU.py
@@ -302,6 +302,11 @@ class BaseCPU(ClockedObject):
node.appendPhandle(phandle_key)
cpus_node.append(node)

+        # Generate nodes from the BaseCPU children (and don't add them as
+        # subnode). Please note: this is mainly needed for the ISA class.
+        for child_node in self.recurseDeviceTree(state):
+            yield child_node
+
yield cpus_node

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
```

## What the patch resolves

The *Linux* kernel uses a *Device Tree Blob* (*DTB*), which is a regular file, to declare the hardware on which the kernel is running. This is used to make the kernel portable between different architecture without a recompilation for each hardware change. The DTB follows the *Device Tree Reference*, and is compiled from a *Device Tree Source* (*DTS*) file, a regular text file. You can learn more [here](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Reference) and [here](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Usage).

The problem was that the *PMU* is supposed to be declared to the *Linux* kernel *via* the *DTB*. You can learn more [here](https://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/pmu.txt) and [here](https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/system/b/embedded-blog/posts/using-the-arm-performance-monitor-unit-pmu-linux-driver). In a simulated system, because the system is specified by the user, *gem5* has to generate a *DTB* itself to pass to the kernel, so the latter can recognize the simulated hardware. However, the problem is that *gem5* does not generate the *DTB* entry for our *PMU*.

## What the patch does

The patch adds an entry to the *ISA* and the *CPU* files to enable *DTB* generation recursion up to find the *PMU*. The hierarchy is the following: CPU => ISA => PMU. Then, it adds the generation function in the *PMU* to generate a unique *DTB* entry to declare the *PMU*, with the proper notation for the interrupt declaration in the kernel.

After running a simulation with our patch, we could see the *DTS* from the *DTB* like this:

```
cd m5out    
# Decompile the DTB to get the DTS.
dtc -I dtb -O dts system.dtb > system.dts
# Find the PMU entry.
head system.dts
```

`dtc` is the *Device Tree Compiler*, installed with `sudo apt-get install device-tree-compiler`. We end up with this `pmu` *DTB* entry, under the root node (`/`):

```
/dts-v1/;

/ {
    #address-cells = <0x02>;
    #size-cells = <0x02>;
    interrupt-parent = <0x05>;
    compatible = "arm,vexpress";
    model = "V2P-CA15";
    arm,hbi = <0x00>;
    arm,vexpress,site = <0x0f>;

    memory@80000000 {
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x00 0x80000000 0x01 0x00>;
    };

    pmu {
        compatible = "arm,armv8-pmuv3";
        interrupts = <0x01 0x04 0xf04>;
    };

    cpus {
        #address-cells = <0x01>;
        #size-cells = <0x00>;

        cpu@0 {
            device_type = "cpu";
            compatible = "gem5,arm-cpu";

[...]
```

In the line `interrupts = <0x01 0x04 0xf04>;`, `0x01` is used to indicate that the number `0x04` is the number of a *PPI* interrupt (the one declared with number `20` in *gem5*, the difference of `16` is explained inside the patch code). The `0xf04` corresponds to a flag (`0x4`) indicating that it is a "active high level-sensitive" interrupt and a bit mask (`0xf`) indicating that the interrupts should be wired to all *PE* attached to the *GIC*. You can learn more [here](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jikos/livepatching/+/9ec0de0ee0c9f0ffe4f72da9158194121cc22807/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/gic.txt).

If the patch works and your `ArmPMU` is declared properly, you should see this message at boot time:

```
  [    0.239967] hw perfevents: enabled with armv8_pmuv3 PMU driver, 32 counters available
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable information, and thanks to the Gem5 developers. When the patched version will be released? I have the stable version (v20.1.0.0 / October 1, 2020), however, I ran in the same problem and till now, I had not find solve it, i.e., I can't access HPCs in simulated ARM in Gem5.

Answer (score 0):

Two quick additions to Pierre's awesome answers:

- for fs.py as of gem5 937241101fae2cd0755c43c33bab2537b47596a2, all that is missing is to apply to fs.py as shown at: https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/37978/1/configs/example/fs.py

  ```
  for  cpu in test_sys.cpu:
      if buildEnv['TARGET_ISA'] in "arm":
          for isa in cpu.isa:
              isa.pmu = ArmPMU(interrupt=ArmPPI(num=20))
              isa.pmu.addArchEvents(
                  cpu=cpu, dtb=cpu.mmu.dtb, itb=cpu.mmu.itb,
                  icache=getattr(cpu, "icache", None),
                  dcache=getattr(cpu, "dcache", None),
                  l2cache=getattr(test_sys, "l2", None))
  ```
- a C example can also be found in `man perf_event_open`