# How to obtain PMU events when running ARM bigLITTLE inside gem5

Tags: arm, perf, gem5

I'm running an ARM full system simulation in gem5 and the configurations I'm using in the commandline is:

```
./build/ARM/gem5.perf configs/example/arm/fs_bigLITTLE.py
--kernel=/home/ting-bazinga/gem5/linux-arm-gem5/vmlinux
--caches 
--disk /home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/disks/aarch64-ubuntu-trusty-headless.img 
--bootscript /home/ting-bazinga/gem5/fs_imgs/test.rcS
```

From the post [Using perf_event with the ARM PMU inside gem5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63988672/using-perf-event-with-the-arm-pmu-inside-gem5) I presume obtaining PMU events in gem5 is possible. However I didn't found the exact method for how to do that.

*perf* can be used to obtain PMU information, on my local machine I can just download the *linux-tools-common* in my terminal to use that tool. But I can't do the same with the simulation. There isn't a perf binary that I can just find online (or maybe anyone can give a hint of how to write this kind of binary?) And I also tried downloading the *linux-tools-common* package, copying it into the disk image then using the *makefile* to compile it. But somehow the *makefile* does not work in the simulated system.

Or can the PMU events be abtained using C code? In the post I mentioned above someone used C code to count the number of mispredicted branches by the branch predictor unit during a specific task. And I can use *perf_event_open* to obtain number of instruction during an execution. However running the *perf_event_open* code requires root, but I cannot use sudo in the simulated system.

Can anybody give me some instructions on how to obtain PMU events in gem5? Many thanks.